# Available options when data violates multiple test assumptions?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, assumptions, normality-assumption

I am confused as to how I should analyse my data since I think it violates almost all possible assumptions.

I applied several hormoneconcentrations to plants and counted the amount of roots. Underneath is part of my dataset.

```
LongRoots0ppm = c(2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2)

LongRoots13ppm = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4)

LongRoots25ppm = c(4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6)

LongRoots50ppm = c(4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 3, 5, 9, 7, 5, 3, 7, 6, 5, 6)

LongRoots100ppm = c(0, 2, 3, 13, 6, 8, 8, 4, 5, 10, 4, 9, 7, 7, 6)

LongRoots200ppm = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

LongRoots400ppm = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

As you can see the variation increases and then decreases with increasing hormone levels. As such, variances are unequal. Because it is count data, the data consists exclusively of positive integers and a lot of zeroes, meaning the data is not normally distributed but more like Poisson or negative binominal. Are there options available to me to use for this dataset that appears to violate multiple assumptions? I want to prove that hormone application increases root formation and if possible to statistically find the optimal concentration.

The authors of the paper that describe the test I used test the homogeneity of variance within treatments with Bartlett's test. Response to the hormone was assessed by calculation of linear regression coefficients which were tested
for significance. But that doesn't seem to be an option for me.

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point. If you say, your data is probably Poisson or neg-bin distributed depending on a concentration on a metric scale, isn't a generalized linear model with a poisson (or neg.-bin.) link function a perfectly natural choice? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression

Answer (score 0):

As you do not specify which kind of model you want to implement, there is no direct answer to what you are asking. But in your last paragraph you are kind of implying that you were aiming to do a linear regression - so I am going to refer to that.

The data itself does not have to be normally distributed. This again means that you do not have to meet any kind of assumption concerning homoscedasticity.

**However** the residuals of the linear regression have to be normally distributed and homoscedastic in order to properly decide wether an estimator is significant or not. (The estimators are consistent and unbiased regardless of those assumptions, **if** the other Gauss-Markov assumptions are met.)

So I guess you might want to create a linear regression model and estimate it. Then check if the residuals are normally distributed/homoscedastic. If this is not the case, you can use robust standard errors for example.

Comment: I am sorry my post is rather confusing. I only have a basic understanding of statistics and my current subject/problem is on (or just over) the limits of my understanding. I basically only know linear regression, but my data - as expected - shows a curve (low-high-low). At the same time my data is count data and with different variance with different hormone treatments (logically the 'high' part has more variation than the 'low' parts). Previously I would use ANOVA + post hoc to compare treatments to conclude which concentration is best, but I understood it's not correct to proceed like this.

Comment: As you probably know, there are several assumptions (Gauss-Markov assumptions) that have to be met in order for the estimators to be unbiased and consistent and so on. You are saying that your data is not normally distributed and shows heteroscedasticity. This is per se not a problem, because the assumptions about normal distribution and homoscedasticity only pertain the residuals, not the dependent/independent variables. So what I am recommending is, just perform a linear regression. Then look at the residuals and decide wether a linear regression model is appropriate or not.

Comment: I recommend you take a closer look on the assumptions that underlie linear regression. As others have mentioned - if the linear regression model appears to be inappropriate, you should take a look at other regression models such as Poisson Regression. But you are drawing the wrong conclusions here. Do then residual diagnostics first, the decide wether the model is appropriate.

Comment: Would you perhaps accept the answer, if I answered your question correctly? Otherwhiles - just ask and I will try to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I did a linear regression and checked the residuals and they are more or less normal, but there are 'long tails'. Besides, the model is a bad fit. As you can see from the data I need something non-linear (data goes from low to high to low, like a parabola). So to avoid this subject I know nothing about (non-linear regression), I was hoping it was (more or less) correct to use e.g. Kruskal-Wallis followed by Dunns. So to treat my continuous indep. variable as a categorical independent variable. But can I do this? If so can I do this for count data as dependent var.?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a zero-inflated neg binom model that accounts for possibly erroneous zeros? Like others have mentioned, your post is rather confusing.